# (Woocommerce) Order by price when entering specific category

Tags: functions, filters, hooks, woocommerce-offtopic

is there a way to order products by price only when a user enters to a specific category?

I kind of know that I can achieve this using hooks in functions.php but I'm not sure on how to achieve this

> **add_filter('function-for-ordering-products','my-custom-function');**

```
function my-custom-function(){

//Step 1. Find the category the user is currently watching
//Step 2.  If the category is "Giftcards" go to step 3
//Step 2.1 If the category is not "Giftcards" go to step 4
//Step 3. Set products order by price
//Step 4. Do nothing

}
```

Can you help me out with that?

In Add_filter do i need to use woocommerce_before_shop_loop?

So the correct filter would be...

> **add_filter('woocommerce_before_shop_loop
>   ','my-custom-function')?**

Answer (score 2):

You can use the filter below, as suggested by @sabarnix at

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939337/woocommerce-different-default-sorting-for-different-categories

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'tk_woocommerce_catalog_orderby');
function tk_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $args ) {
    if( is_product_category( 'shirts' ) ) {
        $args['orderby']  = 'meta_value_num';
        $args['order']    = 'ASC';
        $args['meta_key'] = '_price'; 
    }
    return $args;
}
```